# Is there a hidden ">> return ()" at the end of every main in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, monads

How come I can write something like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= putStrLn
```

Since `getLine :: IO String` and `putStrLn :: String -> IO String` it would seem that the overall type of this action should be `IO String`. Why does this compile instead of giving a type error? The only reason I can come up with is that at compile time `>> return ()` is added to the end of the value of `main`. So what's going on here?

Comment: No. `putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()`, so your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: putStrln has the following Type: `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`. This is also intuitively correct, since we dont expect a String back, we simply want the IO effect of printing to console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`. So there's nothing magical happening at all.

You can also verify this by writing

```
main :: IO String
main = getLine
```

and observing that this both (1) does compile and (2) couldn't possibly compile if there were an implicit `>> return ()` inserted into `main`.

Comment: And three, it wouldn't compile if `main :: IO ()`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Ah, good point! One could imagine the compiler adding `>> return ()` but only when `main :: IO ()`, and your proposed test is a good way to rule that out.